# How to solve the functional equation $f(a+2b)-f(a+1)=f(b)$

Tags: solution-verification, functional-equations

So I was bored, and decided to do a functional equation, which I have never done before. After a while, I came up with this:$$f(a+2b)-f(a+1)=f(b)$$ which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at solving the functional equation:

---

Step $1$: Plug in $a=0$:$$f(2b)-f(1)=f(b)$$$$\implies f(b)=f(1)-f(2b)$$Step $2$: Plug in $f(b)=f(1)-f(2b)$:$$f(a+2b)-f(a+1)=f(1)-f(2b)$$$$\implies f(2b)=f(1)+f(a+1)-f(a+2b)$$$$\text{When we plug in }a=0\text{ again we get} f(2b)=2f(1)-f(2b)$$$$\implies f(1)=f(2b)$$$$\implies f(b)=f(1)=0$$$$\implies f(a+2b)=f(a+1)$$Now, to plug in $b=0$ for Step $3$:$$f(a)=f(a+1)$$This can only be true if the following conditions are met:$$f(a,b)=\begin{cases}c\text{ (where }c\text{ is an unspecified constant)}&,a+2b\ne1\\ 0&,a+2b=1\\ 0&,a=0\end{cases}$$

---

### My question

---

Is my solution to the functional equation correct, or what could I do to solve it more easily?

---

#### Mistakes I might have made

---

1. Everything (I've never done one of these before, so I honestly don't know what I'm doing here)

Comment: You just came up with one? What makes you think it is tractable? Not all functional equations are solveavle.

Comment: What is supposed to be the domain of this function?

Comment: The implication $f(2b)-f(1)=f(b)\implies f(b)=f(1)-f(2b)$ is not correct.

Comment: Your function is of one variable, not two, so it doesn't make sense to define $f(a,b)$ as an answer.

Comment: When constructing your own functional equation, it is often worth starting with a specific function, and fhen determining an equation that works for that function,then check to see if that equation fully determines your original function, or if there are other solutions. This is because it is hard to avoid getting  no answers or only trivial  answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=2b,$ then $f(4b)=f(2b+1)+f(b)$. But by your equality, $f(2n)=f(1)+f(n),$ we get:

$$f(4b)=f(1)+f(2b)=2f(1)+f(b).$$

So we get $f(2b+1)=2f(1),$ for all $b.$

So the function is constant on odd numbers.

If $a=2k-1, b=1$ then $a+2$ is odd, so:

$$2f(1)-f(2k)=f(a+2)-f(2k)=f(1),$$ or $f(2k)=f(1),$ so $f$ must be constant on the even numbers, as well.

But then $$f(1)=f(4)=f(2)+f(1)=2f(1),$$ which means $f(1)=0.$ Then $f(n)=0$ for all $n.$